# Using RTF in VB.NET to create a document

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Thanks for viewing my post. I'm looking for ideas regarding creating a document with rtf. I started using word to create a word document automatically, but word automation does not work too well server side, and it is not recommended to do so by Microsoft. I know how to do basic text with rtf, but I'm wondering if I could create a template with bookmarks and fill in these bookmarks with data from a database. Any ideas would be appreciated. I'm not looking for handouts (ex- coding), just looking for ideas. Thank again for your time! Any info will be greatly appreciated! I'm using asp.net.

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go at this in a new way. I'm going to create a html document with 'placeholders'. Then I will call on the document to save with the .doc extension. Testing has shown that Microsoft Word will open this document. Thanks again.

Josh

```
    Public Function GetTemplate( _
        ByVal strTemplateFile As String) As String

        Dim strPath As String = ""

        strPath = Server.MapPath("~/Templates") & "\" & strTemplateFile
        Return My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(strPath)


    End Function
```

and

```
    Dim strTemplate As String = ""
    Dim blnLB As Boolean = True

    strTemplate = GetTemplate("Legislative_Bulletin.htm")

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword")
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Legislative_Bulletin" & ".doc")
    Response.Write(strTemplate)
    Response.End()
```

this is just example coding. you will still need to insert the data into the placeholders of the html template. I hope this helps someone!

Josh

Answer (score 1):

RTF stand for Rich Text Format.  the toolbox contains a RichTextBox control which will read,edit, and write rtf documents.  You can easily extend this to get the functionality you want.  Here's an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30799/Extended-RichTextBox)

Here's an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/455129/Rich-Text-Editor-with-ASP-NET) of a rich text editing control for asp.net

Comment: There isn't a RichTextBox control for .NET is there? Do you recommend any third party ones? Thank for the reply!

Comment: Yes there is `RichTextBox` in .NET

Comment: the controls are placed in a sidebar of the designer called, surprise surprise, a toolbox.  If you don't see it right away expand `All Windows Forms`

Comment: You can't use a normal RichTextBox in ASP.NET.

Comment: then you should have enough intelligence to use the proper tags to let anyone reading your post know.  There's nothing in your post that mentions asp.net

Comment: There is nothing in my original post, but I did mention it later. To humor you, I removed the rtf tag as well as edited my original post. I did find another way to get to what I was looking for, which I posted as well. Thanks for your intellectual posts.

Comment: The only place I see asp.net, besides what you just added and what I just added, is in one of the later comments here.  I added an example for you for asp.net

Comment: Thanks for the example. This will be useful in the future as well as to others using RTF in asp.net.